# How to capitalise date month whilst using EDATE formula at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

Currently, I am using the `EDATE` function in cell `A5`.

It is displaying the date as "February".

I want this "February" to be displayed as "FEBRUARY". (simple change to upper case)

How can I do this whilst keeping the formula currently in cell `A5`?

Cell `A5` formula : `=EDATE(A4,1)`

Comment: I can only think of doing 12 separate condition formats at the moment - not very practical.

Comment: If you need to use the date in a calculation elsewhere, it would be easier to do that calculation somewhere else and then use a formatted text version in A5.

Comment: Far stretched, but you can install an all-caps font like "Bebas Neue" and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=PROPER(TEXT(EDATE(A4,1),"MMMM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a font which is all capitals e.g.Perpertua Titling MT

[image]

Otherwise conditional format

```
dd \F\E\B\R\U\A\R\Y yyyy
```

with custom formula

```
=month(C1)=2
```

and so on for all 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

If your cell content doesn't need to be a numeric date. Means you don't calculate with this cell and it is just for displaying purpose, then use the following formula

```
=UPPER(TEXT(EDATE(A4,1),"MMMM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

=UPPER(TEXT(EDATE(A4,1),"dd MMMM yyyy"))

This works quite well when using other date functions like e.g. EOMONTH